# System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'oqs' or one of its dependencies. in Docker

Tags: c#, c, asp.net, docker, dllimport

I am trying to run an asp.net mvc app in docker. I have a compiled c binary that it references in my root project directory: `liboqs.dylib`, `liboqs.so`, and `oqs.dll`. It's one compiled c build, but I have the mac, linux, and windows versions of the file so the code can grab whichever one it needs. The code references the file like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private struct OQS_SIG
{
    public IntPtr method_name;
    public IntPtr alg_version;
    public byte claimed_nist_level;
    public byte euf_cma;
    public UIntPtr length_public_key;
    public UIntPtr length_secret_key;
    public UIntPtr length_signature;
    private IntPtr keypair_function; // unused
    private IntPtr sign_function; // unused
    private IntPtr verify_function; // unused
}

#region OQS native DLL functions
[DllImport("liboqs.so", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
extern private static IntPtr OQS_SIG_new(string method_name);

[DllImport("liboqs.so", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
extern private static int OQS_SIG_keypair(IntPtr sig, byte[] public_key, byte[] secret_key);

[DllImport("liboqs.so", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
extern private static int OQS_SIG_sign(IntPtr sig, byte[] signature, ref UIntPtr sig_len, byte[] message, int message_len, byte[] secret_key);

[DllImport("liboqs.so", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
extern private static int OQS_SIG_verify(IntPtr sig, byte[] message, int message_len, byte[] signature, int signature_len, byte[] public_key);

[DllImport("liboqs.so", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
extern private static void OQS_SIG_free(IntPtr sig);

[DllImport("liboqs.so", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
extern private static IntPtr OQS_SIG_alg_identifier(int index);

[DllImport("liboqs.so", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
extern private static int OQS_SIG_alg_count();

[DllImport("liboqs.so", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
extern private static int OQS_SIG_alg_is_enabled(string method_name);
#endregion

/// <summary>
/// List of supported mechanisms. Some mechanisms might have been disabled at runtime,
/// see <see cref="EnableddMechanisms"/> for the list of enabled mechanisms.
/// </summary>
public static ImmutableList<string> SupportedMechanisms { get; private set; }

/// <summary>
/// List of enabled mechanisms.
/// </summary>
public static ImmutableList<string> EnabledMechanisms { get; protected set; }

/// <summary>
/// Static constructor.
/// </summary>
static Sig()
{
    // initialize list of supported/enabled mechanisms
    List<string> enabled = new List<string>();
    List<string> supported = new List<string>();
    int count = OQS_SIG_alg_count();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        string alg = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(OQS_SIG_alg_identifier(i));
        supported.Add(alg);
        // determine if the alg is enabled
        if (OQS_SIG_alg_is_enabled(alg) == 1)
        {
            enabled.Add(alg);
        }
    }
    EnabledMechanisms = enabled.ToImmutableList<string>();
    SupportedMechanisms = supported.ToImmutableList<string>();
}
```

The problem is that I get this error when the code that accesses this binary runs:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'oqs' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: liboqs: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This is my docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy everything
COPY . ./
# Restore as distinct layers
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
COPY liboqs* oqs ./out/

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "amaranth.dll"]
```

Notice that I'm copying the liboqs files into the directory in which the app is being built. I even sshed into my docker container's terminal and found that all 3 liboqs files were in the `app` directory.

It's worth mentioning that the app runs perfectly without docker as long as the liboqs files are in the same directory as the main executable.

So what is the problem? How do I get the app to find the liboqs files?

Comment: Does it work without the .so extension? .NET usually recognizes the corresponding file extension automatically.

You could also try to ssh into your container and check whether there are unresolved symbols in that file.
`ldd -r -d liboqs.so`

Comment: I tried it without the `.so`. It still fails. I didn't try the `ldd -r -d liboqs.so` command yet

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using `DLLImport` with an external Fortran library. The `ldd MyLibrary.so` command as suggested by Robin Lindner highlighted a few missing dependencies.  I needed to include the `-static-intel` parameter to resolve my missing dependencies when compiling:

```
./ifort -shared -fpic -static-intel -o MyLibrary.so MyLibrary.f90
```

There might be a similar issue with the c binary.